# Double Ping bug on chat

Tags: bug, chat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Don't repeat the ping when editing chat messages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115866/dont-repeat-the-ping-when-editing-chat-messages)
>   [I get pinged again when the original post is edited in chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129857/i-get-pinged-again-when-the-original-post-is-edited-in-chat)

In chat if you edit a message with @tzenes in it, then I get pinged a second time.  Once for the original post and once for the edit.

It would seem to me this is not the intention of pinging.

Comment: Whoa - double ping! Full on, all the way!

Comment: Double ping, what does it mean????