# Don't repeat the ping when editing chat messages

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, chat

If you use an @notification in chat messages it will notify the corresponding user with a small circle (or snowman) on their gravatar and (if enabled) a sound effect.

Now, when you have notified a user that way they will be notified again if you edit the message containing the @notification.
I don't think this behaviour is optimal. In most cases I don't really want to ping the user again; I just want to correct some small typo.

I suggest to change the behaviour to not repeat the ping when posts are edited.

Comment: But I care when you fix typos.

Comment: Declining this since it's really more trouble than worth it (we can't just unconditionally not re-ping, there'd have to be some sort of logic as to "does this look like a major edit?"). And the majority seems to agree.

Comment: @balpha plus some of us forget to ping people and go back and edit to ping for the first time! Not that I'd ever forget to do something.

Comment: @balpha In that case, the user can just delete the message and send a new one.  Another option would be to ask the user whether to re-ping, with the default as off.  This wouldn't deter the pranksters, but it would really help.

Answer (score 12):

Implementing this would also remove notification in the case where you *do* want to ping the person again. I don't think it's worth it.

If you really don't want to ping the person again for a minor typo, you have the option of just living with the typo.

Comment: I never had an occasion where I wanted to ping a user again for the same, edited message. I find the behaviour just unexpected, it's confusing to find some phantom ping, cause by some edit.

Comment: @Fabian I don't have much else to say beyond "I've had an occasion where I wanted to ping a user again". :)

Comment: I'd think the larger issue is, implementing this would prevent pinging another individual if, say, you accidentally pinged the wrong person in the first place.

Comment: @Grace it could check if the notifications changed after the edit, if that would be worth the dev-time is another question, of course.

Comment: @Fabian I don't think the pings are much of an annoyance, since you can just click on them and it will track exactly which message(s) caused the ping.

Comment: @Fabian An edit may also change the content non-trivially, in which case it may be nice to be notified.

Comment: If you really do want to ping the person again, you have the option of just...pinging them again. You always have the option of pinging someone; what you can't get around is not pinging them when the system forces you to, so it should avoid that if possible