# Eliminate repinging in chat upon edit

Tags: feature-request, chat, ping

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Don't repeat the ping when editing chat messages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115866/dont-repeat-the-ping-when-editing-chat-messages)

It's quite irritating to have a chat message re-ping several times when it's edited.  Can we change the ping code so that it only re-pings if the `@` was added/changed?

Comment: I've made the same request in "[Don't repeat the ping when editing chat messages](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115866/dont-repeat-the-ping-when-editing-chat-messages)" a while back, it didn't go over all that well.

Answer (score 3):

I'm against this feature request.

When I'm pinged, and the author changed the content of the sentence, I like to have the correction pinged. Even if it's just a typo, it's often something worth a ping.

How cheap is a ping btw?!

Comment: 99% of the time it's just fixing a typo or indentation though?

Comment: pew pew! Waa waa waa waaaaa..... (Pac-man noises :-P)