# Chat pings should use a tag to prevent multiple notifications for one message

Tags: feature-request, chat, notifications

If a user edits a chat message with a ping, there's a double notification.

- Pings that didn't change should not ping again.

  or
- Pings should use [Notification.tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/notification) to prevent two notifications for a single ping. Maybe even for all pings. (`{tag:"ping"}` or `{tag:"ping:"+messageId}`)

Comment: This is why I turned off the volume in chat.

Comment: Strongly related: [Don't repeat the ping when editing chat messages](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/115866) (but `Notification.tag` wasn't around then)

Comment: I would want to be pinged again if I dismissed the notification and then the message was edited afterward. If I haven't read it yet, though, definitely no need to notify me.

Comment: @Emrakul, usually, edits fix typos, if there's a substantial change, just write another message. Determining if a message has been read isn't that easy without tracking our eyes. ;-)