# I get pinged again when the original post is edited in chat

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, chat, ping

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Don't repeat the ping when editing chat messages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115866/dont-repeat-the-ping-when-editing-chat-messages)

Whenever I'm in chat (or out of chat), and someone "@Jae" me, of course I am alerted.
Why am I alerted again when the user edits that chat message? Is this [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), or is it just a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)?

If it is a bug, can we get this fixed?

Comment: By design of course(IMO)--you'd want to be notified if he said something else.

Comment: @Manishearth: But sometimes the user edits his "helo" to say "hello" and so on...

Comment: Good point. Does this ping the multicollider as well? If it's just an in-chat ping, then I see no pr0blem with it, those pings aren't that clutter-y.

Comment: @Manishearth It's not that it is cluttery, but if I leave chat, and then I get "summmoned" again just because he misspelled a word.

Comment: Oh, the noisy-type ping. Let me write something up.

Comment: That is intentional, I posted a [feature request to change that behaviour](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115866/dont-repeat-the-ping-when-editing-chat-messages) a while ago, but from the votes on that one it is clear that most users seem to prefer the current behaviour. I personally find it annoying and don't really encountered cases where the current behaviour would be useful, but I seem to be in the minority.

Comment: @Jae: Nvm, someone else wrote it already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's by design, as you are notified the text is changed; the user could have corrected the link given in that post, for example, or changed something else that you need to read.

Clearly, this happens also when the user fixes a typo, but the system is not able to understand when the user is correcting a typo. There are also cases where letting you know the user fixed a typo could be important for you.

Comment: So is there a way we can fix it so that I am only alerted if the edit changes more than _X_ characters?

Comment: @Jae You could propose a feature-request, but make sure you work on the probable flaws, otherwise it won't last long. :P

Comment: It's not a matter of how many characters are changed, but what it is changed. I could even change the pinged user, or the post to which I am replying. As I said, also a single character being changed could be important, and the system is not able to make a decision about that.

Comment: @Alenanno Sounds good... I'll wait a little until this question dies ;-)

Comment: @Jae [That feature request already exists](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115866/dont-repeat-the-ping-when-editing-chat-messages), you don't need to duplicate it.

Comment: @Fabian Oh you're right. Uhm, forget what I said, Jae. :P

Comment: @Fabian My request would not be abolishing the feature, just changing it so that your only alerted if it is more than a X character edit. Not a duplicate.

Comment: @Alenanno See the above comment.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't be surprised if this received a [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) red tag on it.

Anyway, although you tagged your question with a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) tag, this is not a bug. It's clearly intended, because if they change their post, then you should be notified, since the chat post was explicitly written for/to you.